# assign identical permission to owner and group

Tags: linux, permissions

I want to assign a bunch of folders and files ( around 1000 files and folders ) the same permission to the group as they are for the owner. Is there an easy way to realise it? The normal method would be check manually the owner rights and then do a chmod. Is there an automated way to do this.

For example:

```
-rw-------  1 admin admin  1517 Jul 26 20:00 README.txt
-r--------  1 admin admin  1517 Jul 26 20:00 README2.txt
```

Should be

```
-rw-rw----  1 admin admin  1517 Jul 26 20:00 README.txt
-r--r-----  1 admin admin  1517 Jul 26 20:00 README2.txt
```

And this should be done for each and every file and folder recursively.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/284428/copy-a-files-owner-permissions-to-group-permissions   let me know if you meant something else.

Comment: Thats what I meant. chmod -R g=u * did the job.